# iPhone - Arrange images

Tags: iphone, ios4, uiimageview, uiimage

This question may be silly. Is it possible to arrange three images as in the following attachment? Is it possible to design the `UIImageView` in such manner? If so, how? Share me some useful links. Thank you in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you should look into `QuartzCore`'s **`CGAffineTransformConcat`** / **`CGAffineTransform`** to rotate the images, and `.layer.borderWidth` for the border and `.layer.shadowRadius`and alike for shadow effects.